# Lisp style: setq vs. setf

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Peter Norvig mentions in [Paradigms of Artificial Intelligence Programming](http://norvig.com/paip.html), on [page 50](http://books.google.com/books?id=X4mhySvjqUAC&printsec=frontcover&lr=#PPA50,M1), the trade off between specificity and consistency and when choosing to use setq or setf to update a variable to a value. What do you recommend? Have you ever run into a situation where it mattered much beyond readability?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using setq is more low-level, but the performance of setf is not a problem. And setf allows you (or library writers) to provide custom setf behavior, like setting parts of custom data structures. I say: go with setf everywhere unless you have a reason not to.

Also see Practical Common Lisp, chapter 3: "The SETF macro is Common Lisp's main assignment operator." PCL is available online for free: http://gigamonkeys.com/book/

Answer (score 12):

FWIW, I always use `setf`.  If I change the structure of my code slightly, I just need to change the "place" instead of the place and the operator (setq -> setf).

Also, don't worry about performance, setf is exactly the same as setq for symbols:

```
CL-USER> (macroexpand '(setf foo 42))
(SETQ FOO 42)
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use `setf` wherever you could use `setq`.  In fact,  `setf` is actually a macro which builds on `setq`.  So, this should be purely a readability and style issue.

Almost all the code I've seen avoids the use of `setq` and uses `setf`.

Answer (score 4):

setf is "set field", it changes a *place* and can have user extensions.
setq is set with quoting first argument.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you follow Norvig's final advice in that section: be consistent. 'Readability' is of course the most important reason to make any choice in programming. If it is important to communicate to the reader (perhaps you in 2 months' time) that you are dealing with the entire value cell of a symbol, then use `setq`; otherwise use `setf`. But only if you're being consistent.

Answer (score -2):

You will not be wrong if you used setf everywhere instead of setq.

It's the things like this that drags Common Lisp from going forward, lots of unused stuff that implementors still need to support.

Comment: I object to the second sentence.  SETF is a convenient abstraction over several assignment constructs, one of which is SETQ.  You cannot implement SETF without having SETQ.

Comment: 2Svante: but it's hard to imagine situations where you'd need to use setq instead of setf.

Comment: That's not the point -- no one uses TAGBODY and GO in high level code, either, but the implementations of many common constructs depend on them.